# how can access argv and options together in php through command line arguments

Tags: php, command-line

we have many php scripts running on live servers which use arguments from command line.
Now i need to add one more argument in some of  these crons which will tell me about the environment, which in turn select the server (slave, master). ANd this selection of servers is a central library code.

I dont want to change argument accessed in current scripts. 
so only option is to add this new  environment argument at the end. But in that case there are crons which wont be containing this environment arguments. So i cannot blindly access the last argument in the library.
So i thought to use options for this.

so my script will be run in terminal like
php myscript.php  arg1 arg2  -env slave

but in this case i cannot get options in php  .May be because it mix of arguments supplied directly and with options..

what to do? Any help?

Comment: Could you supply examples of what you have tried? And specifically elaborate on this sentence: "but in this case i cannot get options in php .May be because it mix of arguments supplied directly and with options..".

Answer (score 1):

First search for the option(`-env`) in the array of `argv` get the `key` from array(`$argv`) and increment by 1 to get the value of the option:

```
if (false !== $key = array_search('-env', $argv)) {
    $value = $key+1;
    $env = $argv[$value]; // $env will be 'slave' now.
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

There might be some better options.

referred [PHP if in_array() how to get the key as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836741/php-if-in-array-how-to-get-the-key-as-well) hehe!

Comment: i'm looking for some concrete solution. This is more of hack.
In this case if i want to access the value of env . i need to again do a hack to extract sub string

Answer (score 0):

Try moving options before the arguments when invoking the script.

```
 php myscript.php -e slave arg1 arg2
```

or

```
php myscript.php --env slave arg1 arg2
```

Note: This will change the `$argv` array as the option and its value will show up first in `$argv` array and move other arguments to higher index.