# Laravel, PHP, show value where 2 id match

Tags: php, laravel

From Controller, I'm passing to the view 1 int and 2 arrays and 1 var, the int is `$i = 0;` and the 2 arrays are:

```
dd($myArray);
/*
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    0 => 2
    1 => 0
    2 => "2019-07-21 23:59:59"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    0 => 3
    1 => 2
    2 => "2019-07-21 23:59:59"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    0 => 1
    1 => 1
    2 => "2019-07-21 23:59:59"
  ]
]

*/
```

And:

```
$new_functions = NewFunctions::getAllFunctions();
dd($new_functions);
/*
Collection {#771 ▼
  #items: array:12 [▼
    0 => {#1047 ▼
      +"id": 2
      +"name": "demografico"
      +"dict_key": "demographic"
      +"component": "Demographic"
      +"country_id": null
      +"created_at": null
      +"updated_at": null
    }
    1 => {#1041 ▶}
    2 => {#1040 ▶}
    etc..., like more 10 objects.
*/
```

In the view, I have this code to "combine" those 2 arrays:

```
@foreach($new_functions as $key => $item)
    @if(in_array($item->id, array_column($myArray, 0)))
        <input type="number" id="{!! $item->id !!}" name="function_count[{{$item->id}}]" value="{{ $myArray[$i++][1] }}">
    @else
        <input type="number" id="{!! $item->id !!}" name="function_count[{{$item->id}}]" value="0">
    @endif
@endforeach
```

What I'm trying to is: "if the $item->id , which could be the id of any of the Collection objects, be in the column '0' of $myArray, put in the input of the view, the value of the 2nd position of $myArray, if  isn't present, put 0."

In my local works ok, but in other ambients doesn't works ok, and it's puting values in different order.

How could I decide in the blade view, to put the value of thr 2nd position of $myArray when id of my item be the the value of the first column of the element of $myArray?

Answer (score 0):

I made it with the help of this thread:

[PHP if in_array() how to get the key as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836741/php-if-in-array-how-to-get-the-key-as-well)

What I need was to use:

```
@if(false !== $key = array_search($item->id, array_column($myArray, 0)) )
```

And get rid off of that static loop with `$i`